# syslogins and instance login mismatch

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have few domain user.One of them is testdomain\testlogin. This user is not exist is instance login.when I click security->login I did not found the login 'testdomain\testlogin'. But when I query the the login like
use master
select * from [master].[sys].[syslogins] where name= 'testdomain\testlogin'

I got the login details. How it is possible? Please some one help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In the node 'Security-Logins' are displayed just those logins that has access.

On the other hand, sys.syslogins displays all logins.

Let's se an example, see image below. There are exactly 12 logins on my local instance.

[image]

However, when I issued T-SQL command, as shown in the snippet below

```
select * from sys.syslogins
```

I got 17 logins, as shown in the image below.

[image]

How your domain account gets has access to zero, or status equal to 10, it is another question. Usually, when the user is absent for a long period the DBA disables the account. When the user comes back to work, the DBA enable the account. But although, the account has the same name, has different SID, and cannot connect to SQL server instance. I'm not sure about your concrete scenario, but I hope that this answer will help you.

Comment: right now I disable a user and then delete the user from AD. But found that the user is exist in instance login.So If a user is disabled or delete from AD it remain in instance login but can not connect. But my scenario is quite difference.Any way thank you for the explanation.